# <apply-templates/> vs <apply-templates select="..."/> in XSLT

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

Look at the XSLT-code under the address http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_apply ... Below you find the first part of this code (and the one decisive for my question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
<xsl:apply-templates/>  
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

If you now change only the line

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>
```

the transformation does not work anymore ... (The code now looks as follows:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>  <!--ONLY LINE OF CODE THAT WAS CHANGED-->
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

My question is: Why does the change break the code? In my opinion, the logic is the same in both cases:

1. apply the template matching "cd"
2. inside template "cd" apply the other two templates ("title" + "artist")

UPDATE:

The whole xslt code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's an excerpt from the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
 </cd>
    ......
 </catalog>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of the XML, so this question can be "stand-alone" and doesn't rely on having to click through to W3Schools to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What W3C schools doesn't tell you is about XSLT's [Built-in Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

When you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>` you are positioned on the document node, which is the parent of the `catalog` element. Doing `select="cd"` will select nothing, because `cd` is a child of the `catalog` element, and not a child of the document node itself. Only `catalog` is a child.

(Note that `catalog` is the "root element" of the XML. An XML document can have only one root element).

However, when you do `<xsl:apply-templates />`, then this is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` which will select the `catalog` element. This is where the built-in templates kick in. You don't have a template matching `catalog` in your XSLT, and so the built-in one is used.

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

(Here `*` matches any element). Thus, this built-in template will select the child nodes of `catalog`, and so match the other templates in your XSLT.

Note that, in your second example, you can change the template match to this...

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

This will match the `catalog` element, and so then `<xsl:apply-templates select="cd" />` will work.

Comment: Above link is now broken, but here is a link for XSLT 2.0's built-in template rules: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PER-xslt20-20090421/#built-in-rule